# Show that the inductive sequence is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For $0<\beta <1$ and $a_0,a_1 \in \mathbb{R}^*$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ show that for

$$a_{n+1}=\beta a_{n}+(1-\beta )a_{n-1}$$

$(a_n)$ is konvergent.

As a Hint, we have to express $(a_n)$ in explizite form like $c_1\lambda_1^n+ c_2\lambda_2^n$.

Any idea on this?

Comment: If $a_0 = a_1$, the sequence is constant. Otherwise, what is $\frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{a_n - a_{n-1}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic equation is

$$x^2-\beta x+(\beta-1)=0$$

$$\iff (x-1)(x-\beta+1)=0$$

$$\implies  a_n=A+B(\beta-1)^n$$

but $-1<\beta-1<0$

yes you can finish.

Comment: Thank you! How you find the characteristic function? And does this mean that for $n \rightarrow \infty (a_n)$ is a constant?

Comment: @TylerDur Ea_{n+1}+Fa_n+Ga_{n-1}=0$ gives the equation $Ex^2+Fx+G=0$.